# Cannot get Flutter AppBar theme variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I have problems to get the values from my custom theme for a Flutter application.

I´ve created a flutter theme for my AppBar like this:

```
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      color: Colors.white,
      textTheme: TextTheme(
        headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
      )
    ),
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      headline2: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      headline3: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      bodyText1: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
    )
  ),
```

If I want to get this value with this code:

```
    appBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
      middle: Text("Juni 2020", style: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.textTheme.headline1),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade800,
    ),
```

.. I get the following error:

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building MinistryReport(dirty, state:
flutter: _MinistryReportState#80978):
flutter: The getter 'headline1' was called on null.
flutter: Receiver: null
flutter: Tried calling: headline1
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
              color: Colors.white,
              textTheme: TextTheme(
                headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
              )
          ),
          textTheme: TextTheme(
            headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            headline2: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            headline3: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            bodyText1: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
          )
      ),
      home: MyHome(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       appBar: Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS ? CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: Text("Juni 2020", style: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.textTheme.headline1),
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade800,
    ): AppBar(
         title: Text("Juni 2020", style: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.textTheme.headline1),
         backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade800,
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

Your code works, try this